# Can't download html source from a web page

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, web-crawler

im having problems downloading html source from a web page in android. I run the http client in a different thread and it is able to get the html text ( i logged the result) but later when i try to work with the downloaded html text the variable seems to be empty from the main thread. I assume the problem is rising because im unable to synchronize threads but i don't know how to fix it for now. When i debug the code, the global variable contains data in the run function but when i join threads and look after the join method the variable is empty. Here is my code (class which i run in a different thread)

public class LutrijaHr  {

```
public String url;
public String savedHtml;
public LutrijaHr(String s){
    this.url = s;
    savedHtml = "";
}

public String donwloadSource(String passedUrl) throws Exception{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(passedUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    String html = "";
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();
    savedHtml += html;
    return html;
}
```

}

Parts of code from the main class:

```
String test = "";
LutrijaHr lhr = new LutrijaHr("https://www.lutrija.hr");
@Override
public void run() {


    try {

        test = lhr.donwloadSource(lhr.url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lhr.savedHtml = test;
    Log.d("test", test);

}
```

Here is the part where i try to join the threads but the variable is empty

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.checkNumber){
        Thread t = new Thread(new LotoMain(), "Page thread");
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
            etCheckedNumber.setText(lhr.savedHtml);
            String smrki = test;
            Log.d("testdsadasd", lhr.savedHtml);
            Log.d("BOZO BOZO" ,test) ;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("BOZO BOZO BOZO" ,test) ;
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I would like to solve this problem without using the android asynctask class because i want to learn a bit about threads and how they operate.

Comment: If you need to read/edit data inside your html code, you could try with Jsoup library. It also automatically handles connection. Check also in your manifest that internet permissions are given.

Comment: the log cat isn't showing anything usefull.... it only prints out the html source and the random log which i put after the t.join()... i will put a link to my source code if anyone can download it and check

Comment: http://www16.zippyshare.com/v/Lrtze7nK/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Use "Lock"
Add this code to main class:

```
public Lock workingLock = new ReentrantLock();
String test = "";
LutrijaHr lhr = new LutrijaHr("https://www.lutrija.hr");
@Override
public void run() {


    try {
        workingLock.lock();
        test = lhr.donwloadSource(lhr.url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lhr.savedHtml = test;

    workingLock.unlock;

    Log.d("test", test);

}
```

Now use it in:

if (v.getId() == R.id.checkNumber){
        Thread t = new Thread(new LotoMain(), "Page thread");

```
    try {

        try {
            workingLock.lock();

       } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
       }

        etCheckedNumber.setText(lhr.savedHtml);
        String smrki = test;
        Log.d("testdsadasd", lhr.savedHtml);
        Log.d("BOZO BOZO" ,test) ;

        workingLock.unlock();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("BOZO BOZO BOZO" ,test) ;
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: the sam problem still remains.... i have put my source code in the comments above so if you can check it throw an eye on it. And thanks for your time on such a trivial thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will return the source of a given page as one long string which you can then manipulate however you need, and as its a standalone class/method you can call it on the UI thread or asyc or however you choose to.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class WebPage {
    public static String getWebSource(String Url) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(Url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(inputLine);
        br.close();

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Edit: If you want to call it from the UI thread, android won't by default let you do that. you will need to change the apps thread policy which can by done by running this when the app starts (Required a min API of 9)

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work... i will put my source code online if you can check it i would be thankfull

Comment: yeah thats fine, I'm happy to take a look and see if i can come up with anything

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the problem with declaring

String test = "";
as

static String test = "";

Even if this soultion works i don't understand why it wouldn't work with my original solution. If someone could light up this for me it would be really helpfull